# CSS complex INPUT selector

Tags: html, css

I have several blocks that look like this:

```
<div class='templatechoicedesigncss'>
<img src='/images/templatepics/random(100x140).png' />
<p>
   <input type='radio' name='templatechoice' value='random' checked>Random</p>
</div>
```

Whenever the INPUT field is marked as CHECKED - I need to change CSS to the div with `class=templatechoicedesigncss`.

But I need to do it through pure CSS only - no javascript, jquery or other triggers.
Is that possible?

Comment: CSS limitations: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations (2nd bullet point)

Comment: Why the restrictions on the use of Javascript?

Comment: Other than asking if there is a parent selector in CSS, which was answered, you aren't telling us what you are trying to do.  I'm sure there's a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible without JavaScript.

By the way, a `<p>` inside a `<span>` is bad markup, because span's are inline elements and p's are paragraphs.

Also, put the text "Random" inside a `<label>`.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not change **parent** css with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible your way.
Check this http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked

It says...

> Radio and checkbox elements can be toggled by the user. Some menu
>   items are "checked" when the user selects them. When such elements are
>   toggled "on" the :checked pseudo-class applies. While the :checked
>   pseudo-class is dynamic in nature, and can altered by user action,
>   since it can also be based on the presence of semantic attributes in
>   the document, it applies to all media. For example, the :checked
>   pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4
>   selected and checked attributes as described in Section 17.2.1 of
>   HTML4, but of course the user can toggle "off" such elements in which
>   case the :checked pseudo-class would no longer apply.

...exactly, word to word.

which basically means **you can change dynamically the properties of the what is checked** in CSS3 but not it's parent. but oh, it's not fully supported in browsers. other way is to use JS | jQuery | MooTools | YUI etc

Also,  BoltClock pointed out that there is no parent selector in CSS; so not possible via only CSS

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `:checked` pseudo-class. It has to do with there being no parent selector in CSS.